# Java program is hanging

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a program that accepts numbers and generates a table depending on the number of numbers inputted. The program is working fine up to 4 numbers but when I try the same program with 5, the program hangs. A screenshot of the JFrame.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfNcI.png (I don't have enough reputation to post images.)

The button stays pressed but the next part of the program doesn't get executed, and I can't click any other button, nor can I close the window.

Any idea why this is happening and how it can be avoided?

EDIT: This is the method that is supposed to be executed when the button is pressed.

```
public void punnett5(final List<String> fin){
    JFrame gamFrame = new JFrame();

    Object row[][] = {};
    Object column[] = {};
    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(row, column);

    JTable punnett = new JTable(model);

    for (int b = 0; b < 32; b ++){
        model.addColumn("");
    }

    String a1 = "", a2 = "", a3 = "", a4 = "", a5 = "";
    String[] rowData = new String[32];
    int a = 0, first = 0, second = 0, finale = 0;

    for(int b = 11111; b <= 22222; b += 10000){
        for(int c = b; c <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c).substring(0,1)) * 10000) + 2222; c += 1000){
            for(int d = c; d <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(d).substring(0,1)) * 10000) +
                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(d).substring(1,2)) * 1000) + 222; d += 100){
                for(int e = d; e <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e).substring(0,1)) * 10000) +
                        (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e).substring(1,2)) * 1000) +
                        (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e).substring(2,3)) * 100) + 22; d += 10){
                    for(int f = e; f <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(0,1)) * 10000) +
                            (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(1,2)) * 1000) +
                            (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(2,3)) * 100)
                            + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(3,4)) * 10) + 2; d ++){
                        a = 0;
                        first = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(0,1)) * 1000000000) +
                                (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(1,2)) * 10000000) +
                                (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(2,3)) * 100000) +
                                (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(3,4)) * 1000) +
                                (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f).substring(4,5)) * 10);
                        for(int g = 11111; g <= 22222; g += 10000){
                            for(int h = g; h <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(h).substring(0,1)) * 10000) + 2222; h += 1000){
                                for(int i = h; i <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i).substring(0,1)) * 10000) +
                                        (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i).substring(1,2)) * 1000) + 222; i += 100){
                                    for(int j = i; j <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(j).substring(0,1)) * 10000) +
                                            (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(j).substring(1,2)) * 1000) +
                                            (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(j).substring(2,3)) * 100) + 22; j += 10){
                                        for(int k = j; k <= (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(0,1)) * 10000) +
                                                (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(1,2)) * 1000) +
                                                (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(2,3)) * 100)
                                                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(3,4)) * 10) + 2; k ++){
                                            second = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(0,1)) * 100000000) +
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(1,2)) * 1000000) +
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(2,3)) * 10000) +
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(3,4)) * 100) +
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(k).substring(4,5)));

                                            finale = first + second;

                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(0,2))) == 11){
                                                a1 = (fin.get(0) + fin.get(0)).toUpperCase();
                                            }
                                            if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(0,2))) == 12 ||
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(2,4))) == 21){
                                                a1 = fin.get(0) + fin.get(0).toLowerCase();
                                            }
                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(0,2))) == 22){
                                                a1 = (fin.get(0) + fin.get(0)).toLowerCase();
                                            }

                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(2,4))) == 11){
                                                a2 = (fin.get(1) + fin.get(1)).toUpperCase();
                                            }
                                            if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(2,4))) == 12 ||
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(2,4))) == 21){
                                                a2 = fin.get(1) + fin.get(1).toLowerCase();
                                            }
                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(2,4))) == 22){
                                                a2 = (fin.get(1) + fin.get(1)).toLowerCase();
                                            }

                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(4,6))) == 11){
                                                a3 = (fin.get(2) + fin.get(2)).toUpperCase();
                                            }
                                            if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(4,6))) == 12 ||
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(4,6))) == 21){
                                                a3 = fin.get(2) + fin.get(2).toLowerCase();
                                            }
                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(4,6))) == 22){
                                                a3 = (fin.get(2) + fin.get(2)).toLowerCase();
                                            }

                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(6,8))) == 11){
                                                a4 = (fin.get(3) + fin.get(3)).toUpperCase();
                                            }
                                            if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(6,8))) == 12 ||
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(6,8))) == 21){
                                                a4 = fin.get(3) + fin.get(3).toLowerCase();
                                            }
                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(6,8))) == 22){
                                                a4 = (fin.get(3) + fin.get(3)).toLowerCase();
                                            }

                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(8,10))) == 11){
                                                a5 = (fin.get(4) + fin.get(4)).toUpperCase();
                                            }
                                            if((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(8,10))) == 12 ||
                                                    (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(8,10))) == 21){
                                                a5 = fin.get(4) + fin.get(4).toLowerCase();
                                            }
                                            if ((Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(finale).substring(8,10))) == 22){
                                                a5 = (fin.get(4) + fin.get(4)).toLowerCase();
                                            }
                                            rowData[a] = String.format(a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5);
                                            a ++;

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        model.addRow(rowData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    punnett.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);      
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(punnett, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    gamFrame.add(pane);

    gamFrame.setSize(1500,500);
    gamFrame.setTitle("Pentahybrid cross");
    gamFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

the List fin here is {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}

Comment: Probably need to see some code - are any exceptions being thrown to the console when you do this?

Comment: you need to post code for what happens when you click that button

Comment: @Bret No, no errors on the console. 
Added the method that is supposed to be executed.

Comment: add some source code to see where is the problem...

Comment: try to add this method into an other Thread(maybe is timing and running problem)...

Comment: Take a thread dump and see why the AWT thread is blocked

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *"The button stays pressed"*  Guess based on those words - the action blocks the EDT..  (But I don't like guessing, so post an MCVE.)

Comment: I'm REALLY curious. What is this suppose to output? 10 for loops and 15 if-statements? To help decrease processing time use else-if statements with those if statements. Group if-statements 2,3 to use else-if;  5,6 to use else-if; 8,9 to use else-if; 11,12 to use else-if; and 14, 15 to use else-if. This will decrease running time by plenty!

Comment: @Luminous This is supposed to output a table (Punnett Square) to show the possible off-springs with 5 dominant/recessive traits in consideration. With 5 traits, there will be 32 gametes and as a result the table will have 33 rows and 33 columns.

Answer (score 1):

- Part **1**:(**possible problem**)

Your code has to many for.... To much work for the main Thread..
Try to run this method into another Thread so you can press and The other buttons.

The mainReason that your programm lag is that the **main Thread**  is trying to end the **method(you call)** and until it finish with this it dont respond to anything.

- Part **2**:(**example of a Thread**)

  *Call the method like this:*(Basically you need an **extra Thread** to share the work in your proggram)

  ```
  new Thread(new Runnable(){

   public void run(){


  //Here i call The method i want();

  }}).start;
  ```

  ***or you can put the thread to be the body of your method*** or or or...

I am facing this problem to much times with *java swing...*

And something more(if you havent work with Threads add a comment and i will add more things about *java - Threads*).

Let me know if that worked for you...

- Part **3**(***Help working with Threads + one suggested solution***)

  More Help on how to work with Threads(from beginner to Super)

  These are some good tutorials to have a complete view:
  [First link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html)

And of course oracle documentation for better understand....[oracle Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Also try this With your code:

```
public void punnett5(final List<String> fin){

   new Thread(new Runnable(){

     public void run(){

       //Your Method here..

        JFrame gamFrame = new JFrame();

       Object row[][] = {};
       Object column[] = {};

        .......

       JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(punnett,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,   JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
gamFrame.add(pane);

gamFrame.setSize(1500,500);
gamFrame.setTitle("Pentahybrid cross");
gamFrame.setVisible(true);

    }}).start;
```

}

Comment: No, I haven't worked with Threads. I'll try to look up some tutorials.